# Parsing though JSON-data and getting one Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sapui5

I am getting a simple JSON data structure with phone numbers, fax numbers and mobile numbers in a SAPUI5 application:

```
{
    "teles": [
                {"tele": "05312024040", "default": true},
                {"tele": "017666254336", "default": false},
                {"tele": "017666224336", "default": false}
    ],
    "faxs": [
                {"fax":"053155599755", "default": true},
                {"fax":"01548568745", "default": false}
    ],
    "mobils": [
                {"mobil":"017655994816", "default": true},
                {"mobil":"01548568745", "default": false}
    ]
 }
```

My goal is to loop/parse through the Data structure and get the number that is default, and put it into another model with the name "tele-standard", "fax-standard" or "mobil-standard". This should happen before displaying the data, so It can be put into these TextFields, that are editable:

[image: Four TextFields with an option to open a dialog to edit.]

I don't know at all how to do that with jquery, or sapui5 or javascript so I can reach my goal. Can you maybe help?

Results in the new model should look like:

```
{
    "archived": "-", 
    "nummer": "12", 
    "anrede": "Herr",
    "vorname": "Osamah", 
    "nachname": "Al-Doaiss",
    "tele-default": "05312024040",
    "fax-defaule": "053155599755",
    "mobil-default": "017655994816"
}
```

TL;DR: I have a JSON with Arrays. I want to parse through them and get the default number. No idea how!

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/mk8z8bvL/1/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

## 1

```js
var data = {
    "teles": [
        {"tele": "05312024040", "default": true},
        {"tele": "017666254336", "default": false},
        {"tele": "017666224336", "default": false}
    ],
    "faxs": [
        {"fax":"053155599755", "default": true},
        {"fax":"01548568745", "default": false}
    ],
    "mobils": [
        {"mobil":"017655994816", "default": true},
        {"mobil":"01548568745", "default": false}
    ]
};

var model = {
    "archived": "-", 
    "nummer": "12", 
    "anrede": "Herr",
    "vorname": "Osamah", 
    "nachname": "Al-Doaiss"
};

Object.keys(data).forEach(function (key) {
    data[key].forEach(function (el) {
        var keys = Object.keys(el),
            key  = keys.join('-');

        if (el.default && el.default === true && !model[key]) {
            model[keys.join('-')] = el[keys[0]];
        }
    });
});

console.log(model);
```

## 2

```js
var data = {
    "teles": [
        {"tele": "05312024040", "default": true},
        {"tele": "017666254336", "default": false},
        {"tele": "017666224336", "default": false}
    ],
    "faxs": [
        {"fax":"053155599755", "default": true},
        {"fax":"01548568745", "default": false}
    ],
    "mobils": [
        {"mobil":"017655994816", "default": true},
        {"mobil":"01548568745", "default": false}
    ]
};

var model = {
    "archived": "-", 
    "nummer": "12", 
    "anrede": "Herr",
    "vorname": "Osamah", 
    "nachname": "Al-Doaiss"
};

Object.keys(data).forEach(function (key) {
    data[key].forEach(function (el) {
        var keys = Object.keys(el),
            key  = keys.join('-');

        if (el.default && el.default === true && !model[key]) {
            model[key] = el[keys[0]];
        }
    });
});

console.log(model);
```

Answer (score 2):

see this

```js
var numbers = {
    "teles": [
                {"tele": "05312024040", "default": true},
                {"tele": "017666254336", "default": false},
                {"tele": "017666224336", "default": false}
    ],
    "faxs": [
                {"fax":"053155599755", "default": true},
                {"fax":"01548568745", "default": false}
    ],
    "mobils": [
                {"mobil":"017655994816", "default": true},
                {"mobil":"01548568745", "default": false}
    ]
 };

function getAllDefaultNumbers(nums) {
    var outObj = {};
    (Object.keys(nums) || []).forEach(function (number_type) {
        (nums[number_type] || []).forEach(function (obj) {
            if (obj.default) {
                outObj[number_type + '-default'] = obj.tele || obj.fax || obj.mobil;
            }
        });
    });
    return outObj;
}

document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(getAllDefaultNumbers(numbers));
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider data to be your object :

```
for(var phone in data.teles) {
    if(phone.default == true) {
        // Example on how to set phone number with jquery
        $('#defaultPhone').val(phone.tele);
        // You would need an input with the id defaultPhone for this
    }
}
```

Edit: with regards to Your update you would probably to somethin like this (consider variable result as your results object)

```
result.tele-default = phone.tele //instead of the jquery part in the upper example
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code snippet is for getting the default telephone number.
vals  will store your JSON data.

```
     objJson =   JSON.parse(vals);
      var tele_default;
      if(objJson.teles.count>0){
        for(int i=0;i<objJson.teles.count;i++){
            if(objJson.teles[i].default == "true"){
                tele_default = objJson.teles[i].tele
             }
          }
      }
```